# Is there any Netcat like application available in Android OS by default, like most of the Linux systems?

Tags: linux

In most Linux systems Netcat is installed by default. Is any Netcat-like application installed by default in Android OS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In recent Androids (e.g. Nougat and later), you don't need to install busybox for running netcat; it is enough to get a terminal and then type:

> `toybox nc [options]`

and you will have the usual netcat functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Not natively. You first need to install a Terminal application like "Termux" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en then "Busybox" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en. Here is some info on all of the tools included in the Busybox package https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html

There are also several other Netcat style applications available from the Google Play store - https://play.google.com/store/search?q=netcat&c=apps&hl=en

Comment: Termux from the play store is deprecated if i understood correctly.. you need to download it from F-Droid now (or the APK file from their website if you don't mind updating manually every time)
And btw you don't need busybox, just do inside Termux :
$ pkg install netcat

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple GUI app anyone can use without prior knowledge in netcat.

[https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nikedlab.netcat&hl=en][1]

It also has port scanning facility with filtering ports and timeout.